# QSerialPort - setReadBufferSize

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I currently have an issue. I am trying to write a real-time plotting program. I receive data from an Arduino. I can successfully open the serial port and read the information properly and plot the graph as well. The problem is, if I don't specify a buffer size, the input buffer is assumed to be infinite (now reading data at 300Hz-4800Hz you can imagine your computer's memory will probably fill up eventually and everything crashes!).

Now I have tried something like:

```
serial->setReadBufferSize(5000);
```

Now this does successfully set the buffer size, I used `serial->readBufferSize()` to confirm whether it worked or not.

The problem is once the buffer is full, the program stops plotting. Now I imagine what I should do is:

1. Set the buffer size (only once)
2. Read the serial port
3. Plot the data
4. Clear the buffer (serial->clear()).

Repeat steps 2 - 4.

But this doesn't seem to work.

I am making use of `QCustomPlot` to do real-time plotting.

Comment: Reading the serial data removes it from the buffer.  I don't understand your problem.  If you are reading the data faster than it's being received, the buffer should not fill up.  If you are not, use RS232 flow-control.   Why would you want to clear the buffer?  That will just throw away data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read data in an asynchronous way. Just connect the `readyRead()` signal of `QSerialPort` to a slot. `readyRead()` is emitted whenever new data is available :

```
connect(&serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));
```

`readData()` is a slot that is called everytime `QSerialPort` emits the `readyRead()` signal. `readData()` appends any available data to a `QByteArray` class member. You can check in this slot whether a specific amount of data is received or not :

```
void MyClass::readData()
{
    receivedData.append(serial.readAll());

    if(receivedData.count()>=5000)
    {
        //Plot data and remove plotted data from receivedData
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Nejat, thank you for your response. To solve my problem I ended up doing something similar to what you suggested. I just go     if (serial->size() >= 10000)
        serial->clear();

And now my serial buffer clears every time.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your serial.waitForReadyRead is not very small.

```
serial.waitForReadyRead(50)
```

50 ms works for me.